# Are there any latex beauty salons?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, book-design

I am putting together my notes on certain topics in mathematics as a latex document. While I am fairly fluent in latex for all practical purposes, my learning has mostly been adhoc. I don't think I have good style, and the document looks cluttered and could really use a lot of improvement.

While learning good latex is definitely something I need to get on, its not top priority right now. Getting into the nitty-gritties of latex documentation is a huge procrastination-trap I want to avoid, since the mathematical content I am working on deserves and demands my full attention.

So are there any services that offer latex editing and beautification? What I mean is I send them a crude latex document with all content filled in, and they spruce it up with tasteful formatting and appropriate aesthetics to make the final product look beautiful.

If there are tex lovers who do this for free just so they can sharpen their own latex skills, all the better for me :-)
But just curious if there exist paid services too.

Comment: Another question: What do you mean by "final product"? Do you mean "beautiful (La)TeX code" or "beautiful output (PDF or whatever)"?  I believe there are many people who would layout your text for you, and some of them might even be able to use LaTeX.

Comment: If someone could comment with a coherent reason for closing this, I'd like to see it.  Here are some reasons *not* to close: the question is *not* asking about how to beautify a whole document, but whether there are services that offer such help.  The question is also not asking about what makes a document beautiful. So answers to the question will not be subjective (although they may run into problems with the ban on advertising). The question also doesn't belong on meta since it does not pertain to TeX.se the site.

Comment: A somewhat related question: I write something in LaTeX but I wonder whether I could have written it more efficiently. Is it acceptable to post a MWE and ask whether the code could be more efficient? I learn this way but I do not know whether that is acceptable behavior here. Some answers to (other) questions suggest alternative methods but not all answers do.

Comment: @MikeTaylor I think the consensus is code review questions are off topic.  [To what extent are code-review style questions welcome?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6382/2693).

Comment: I might do it. I've never been handed LaTeX, but I have done typesetting jobs in the past where I've been handed something much less coherent than a LaTeX document. I don't know about making it beautiful exactly - I don't do graphic design. Clarity, simplicity and elegance, maybe (but others might disagree, of course).

Comment: TUG has a list of consultants available for work. Some of them may also do more by way of graphic design.

Comment: @MikeTaylor I think it depends on the particular case. The answers linked by Alan Munn are not really definitive. One is against for reasons which we happily ignore in lots of other cases. The other points to Code Review, but I'm not sure how much luck you'd have with TeX code there. Also, there are certainly questions of this kind here. I would say that it depends on how well focused the question is. If you are posting a whole `.cls` or `.pkg` or document, not really suitable. If you are asking whether there's better way to change page layout mid-document or define this macro, probably fine.

Comment: If you are interested in improving your LaTeX file(s), you can contact me for conditions. :-)

Comment: Thanks all. I'm content to wallow in my (sometimes) mediocre code. :)

Answer (score 5):

### Answer to the more implicit question of the question

Beautifying whole documents is not on-topic here. Such questions will likely be closed as off-topic, as too broad, or as opinion based.

Therefore, it is better to present a single problem with a nice [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Also, the tag [best-practices](/questions/tagged/best-practices) exists for questions, how to solve a problem the best way.

### Answer to the explicit question of the question

Of course, there are TeXnicians that can be hired:

- A list is maintained by the TUG (TeX User Group): [TeX Consulting and Production Services](http://tug.org/consultants.html)
- Ask a TeXnician for time and payment conditions.
- ...

Comment: You say the question is not on-topic here. I'd suggest casting a vote-to-close...

Comment: I think [TeX-LaTeX Meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com) is the best place for the question. The appropriate vote-to-close is cast.

Comment: The first part of this answer is not answering the question since the OP is not asking for such advice. The second is  clearly a partial answer although TeXnicians are not necessarily offering style advice, although some may.

Comment: @AlanMunn Asking questions and learning from the answers is good way to improve the LaTeX skills: "While learning good latex is definitely something I need to get on".

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Undoubtedly, but it's not what the OP is asking: "but it's not top priority now [... and] is a huge procrastination-trap".

Comment: @AlanMunn A question remains a question even if it is not top priority. If the question was not important to him, then he could better saved his time for improving the math. Also, the classification "not top priority" is restricted by "right now". That does not prohibit to read the answers right now. Then, when time allows, he can use the answers. And there can be other readers of the question, that might be interested in an answer. An answer is not restricted to the wishes of the OP alone.

Comment: Yes, and the question that remains is clear: "are there any services that offer latex editing and beautification?". Nothing further. Or are you suggesting that the OP should abandon asking this question and instead ask a series of entirely different questions related to specific issues about formatting he needs help with, even though he's stated that he doesn't have the time to devote to learning more LaTeX at the moment.

Comment: @AlanMunn I have just answered the (implicit  and explicit) questions of the question. Feel free to have a different opinion, but I should be allowed to have mine.

Comment: Of course you're allowed to have yours, but closing a question because there is an *implicit* question that is off topic seems unwarranted. The second part of your question absolutely answers the explicit question though, and so I don't understand why you think the question is off topic, that's all.

Comment: @AlanMunn I did not say this.  I only said, if someone posts a whole crude document (thesis, whatever) and asks for beautifying the whole stuff, then this would be off-topic. If the OP's question as whole is off-topic or on-topic was and is *not* of my concern. There are more experienced people around to decide this.

Comment: @AlanMunn Isn't it more a vote to move the question than to close it? Is your point that it ought not be moved to Meta? It seems more on-topic here than there, to me, but that doesn't seem to be the consensus.

Comment: @cfr Well it's clearly not a Meta question since it doesn't pertain to the site itself. And I think it's perfectly on-topic for the main site. But none of the close voters has offered an explanation as to why it should be closed from the main site. Heiko has bowed out of that debate, it seems.

Comment: @Heiko: Imho you should add that the TUG-list contains only services who have payed a yearly fee to get into this list/advertisement.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer There is an deleted answer, where barbara beeton says that payment is only required for the printed TUGboat.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Barbara said something similar in the chat, the web page says something different. She will check.

Comment: Hi. Closing or not closing the question is up to you experts. I am aware that posting a whole document and asking for it to be edited is condemnable. All I asked is if there are volunteers/professionals this can be outsourced to. As for learning latex, I have certainly learned a lot by browsing here. At this point, my requirements are more subtle though: involving some standarization of math syntax, alignments, book templates, etc. I could pick out issues one-by-one and post questions out of them, but as I mentioned, that isn't something I can indulge in at the moment. Thanks.